# How do I extract a repeating string pattern from multiple rows?

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql

I have the following data:

```
|  ID  |                 BadCol                        | 
+------+-----------------------------------------------+         
|  1   | All of R489804 R489805 R489806 R489807 R489808|    
|  2   | SP fr R308999                                 |           
|  3   | R308777, R104621, R708931                     |
```

I'm only interested in the R###### pattern (which will always be an R followed by 6 numerical characters). I can retrieve the location of first occurrence using the following function:

```
PATINDEX('R[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', BadCol)
```

Ideally I'd like to pivot the pattern into it's own row like so:

```
|  ID  | GoodCol | 
+------+---------+         
|  1   | R489804 |    
|  1   | R489805 |    
|  1   | R489806 |    
|  1   | R489807 |    
|  1   | R489808 |    
|  2   | R308999 |           
|  3   | R308777 |  
|  3   | R104621 |  
|  3   | R708931 |
```

I've seen some great resources on how to do this when the data is delimited the same way, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows). Unfortunately the data in this column is delimited differently from row to row. I've also explored a recursive CTE like what is detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726111/sql-server-find-nth-occurrence-in-a-string), but unfortunately both of these methodologies use CHARINDEX() which allows an optional [start_location](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) parameter. PATINDEX() unfortunately [does not](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395(v=sql.110).aspx) take a start_location parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample of how I would do this:

```
select 
      a.id
    , substring(a.value,T.N,7)
from 
    (
    values
        (1,'All of R489804 R489805 R489806 R489807 R489808'),   
        (2,'SP fr R308999                                 '),          
        (3,'R308777, R104621, R708931                     ')
    ) a(id,value)
cross apply (select N from Tally where N<len(a.value)-5) T(N)
where substring(a.value,T.N,7) like 'R[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]';
```

Here, I am using a Tally (or numbers) table to walk the length of each value, extracting substrings of length 7 that match the required format.

Answer (score 1):

You have different delimiters but I'm sure you have a small set of them.  In your sample data the two delimiters are "space" and "comma-space".  You can amend one of the linked solutions to work with multiple matching conditions.  This will deliver unpivoted values.  The data will then look something like

```
1  All
1  of
1  R489804
1  R489805
...
2  SP
2  fr
2  R308999
3  R308777
3  R104621
...
```

Applying your `LIKE` condition to this rowset will give the values you seek, eliminating those rows with "noise" values.